# Parse_url not working correctly on staging server

Tags: php, parse-url

I am facing a problem with parse_url function.
if i use parse_url on my local system i am getting following output.
Url for parsing used is www.youtube.com/embed/u-j1nx_HY5o

```
Array
(
    [host] => www.youtube.com
    [path] => /embed/u-j1nx_HY5o
)
```

But i parse same url on staging i got following output.

```
Array(
    [path] => //www.youtube.com/embed/u-j1nx_HY5o
)
```

ie. I am not getting host name on staging server.

Note : PHP version on staging server is  5.3.3.
Can anyone let me know why its happening.

Many Thanks,

M.

Comment: PHP version greater than `5.4.7`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug prior 5.4.7: `5.4.7 Fixed host recognition when scheme is omitted and a leading component separator is present.`

Check if your staging server's version is lower than 5.4.7.

As an additional advice: Always use the exactly same version and configuration (except the error reporting settings) in all of your environments.

**EDIT**

If you can not update your staging environment, adding the scheme to the URL (http:// for example) could help. Also downgrade your development environment to the version running on staging and production environment.

Comment: Thanks Pred, is there any hack to get rid of this problem without changing php verstion on staging?